# error on "cordova platform add android"

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, ant, sencha-touch-2

I've been searching the net whole day for the answer, but everyone seems to be pointing to the environment variables, well currently I have these settings on my environtment

```
ANT_HOME
C:\java\ant

JAVA_HOME
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45

PATH values
C:\Program Files\nodejs;
%JAVA_HOME%\bin;
%ANT_HOME%\bin;
C:\Users\Julius Robles\Documents\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\tools;
C:\Users\Julius Robles\Documents\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\platform-tools;
C:\Users\Julius Robles\Documents\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\build-tools;
```

I'm assume that these are all that I need, but still I'm unable to add the android platform.

I also tried importing cordova framework in ecplise but keeps showing the error that it couldn't run android libraries.

Any ideas guys?

Ive got these things installed in my unit Windwos 7(x64):
**Sencha** - Sencha Cmd v4.0.1.45
**Cordova** - 3.4.0-0.1.3
**Ant** - Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3
**Node** - v0.10.24
**Phonegap** - 3.4.0-0.19.7

ERROR LOGS from my CMD are here:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\MyIO>cordova platform add android
Creating android project...

C:\Users\Julius Robles\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.j
s:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: An error occurred while listing Android targets
    at C:\Users\Julius Robles\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\lib\check_r
eqs.js:87:29
    at _rejected (C:\Users\Julius Robles\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\
node_modules\q\q.js:808:24)
    at C:\Users\Julius Robles\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_module
s\q\q.js:834:30
    at Promise.when (C:\Users\Julius Robles\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\b
in\node_modules\q\q.js:1079:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\Julius Robles\.cordova\lib\andr
oid\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:752:41)
    at C:\Users\Julius Robles\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_module
s\q\q.js:574:44
    at flush (C:\Users\Julius Robles\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node
_modules\q\q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\Julius Robles\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_mo
dules\cordova\src\superspawn.js:112:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:735:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:802:5)

C:\xampp\htdocs\MyIO>
```

Anyone is free is to answer, Thanks in advance

Comment: Cross check your JAVA_HOME path.

Answer (score 1):

Add `ANDROID_HOME` variable to your environment variables.

ANDROID_HOME

```
C:\Users\Julius Robles\Documents\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\tools
```

Then add the following to your path variable

```
%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;
```

Comment: Hi, is that different from this one?

C:\Users\Julius Robles\Documents\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\tools;

Comment: You need to add `tools` and `platform-tools`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when integrating phonegap and sencha touch when creating the apk (when running this "sencha app build -run native"). I solved it running CMD in administrator mode.

Answer (score 0):

ANDROID_HOME should be C:\Users\Julius Robles\Documents\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030
and PATH should be added 
%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;
%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools;

Answer (score 0):

For the new comers and have tried setting all these environment variables:

- *JAVA_HOME* = `C:\Program Files\Java\jdkx.x.x_XX\bin`
- *ANDROID_HOME* = `C:\Users\You\Android\sdk\platform-tools;C:\Users\You\Android\sdk\tools`
- *ANT_HOME* = `C:\Users\You\Ant\apache-ant-x.x.x\bin`
- *PATH* = `...;%JAVA_HOME%;%ANDROID_HOME%;%ANT_HOME%;`

When in a `CLI` environment i.e *Command Prompt*, *Terminal*,...

Try to use this command(or synonymous commands in your system) even though it is already set.

`set path="C:\Program Files\Java\jdkx.x.x_XX\bin";%Path%`

**This works for me!**